# ASP.NET MVC 5 Controller JsonResult Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Why do I get a `500 Internal server error`?

C#

```
 public JsonResult GetCategory(string id)
        {
                long eocategoryid = Convert.ToInt64(id);
                dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
                ttCategory cat = db.ttCategories.First(x => x.ID == eocategoryid);

                return Json(new
                {
                    catgeory = cat
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

 }
```

JS:

```
 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "/GetCategory",
                     data: { id: data.node.a_attr.id },
                     datatype: "json",
                     success: function (data) {
                         console.log(data);
                    }
                 });
```

Comment: Check the value of your `eocategoryid`. What is it?

Comment: the value is right, cat is set

Comment: not sure you need to specify `datatype: "json"`

Comment: This is not a problem for sure, but you have a typo in `catgeory`. Also, have you tried running debug mode? Do you receive any exceptions in controller?

Comment: i don't get exceptions in the controller. typo doesn't matter.

Comment: Check my answer please. Hope it helps.

Comment: can you give more details for the exception you are seeing, perhaps you could debug and see the exception thrown by the controller

Comment: Well, 500 means that there is an exception on the server side, but perhaps not in the controller code. Two ways I can think of how you can see the actual error. 1) Make sure to [enable all exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) for the debug - that should show you the exception while debugging; 2) In web.config make sure [custom errors are off](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - that should show you the details of the error in the response body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem lies in the serialization process. I think `ttCategory` is an auto-generated class from Entity Framework. **Don't try to serialize the whole class**. Only take the fields you need and return it to the client.

Example return:

```
return Json(new
                {
                    firstName = cat.FirstName,
                    lastName = cat.LastName,
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: yes, this works. I'm unsure why I don't get an exception, e.g. for cycles.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Please check @Andrei comment to make sure that you enabled all exceptions and turned off custom error :)